# How can I give others permission to read my INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA in BigQuery?

Tags: permissions, google-bigquery, information-schema

What privileges can I grant to let everyone in the world query my information schema? i.e. I want everyone to be able to run:

```
select * from `projectid`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

Currently I get back:

```
Access Denied: Table projectid:INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA: User does not have permission to query table projectid:INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually in BigQuery you set permissions at the dataset level. For example, this query will run for anyone, as the dataset is public for everyone:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
```

But you can't do this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `fh-bigquery.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`
```

This because you need project level permissions to see all my datasets, even the ones I haven't made public.

If you really want to share the schemas of all your datasets with the world, then you could create a custom role just for this, with the `bigquery.datasets.get` permission:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles

Then you need to assign this role to all users - but that's not an option.

At the project level, you can assign this role to one of these:

```
Google Account email: user@gmail.com
Google Group: admins@googlegroups.com
Service account: server@example.gserviceaccount.com
G Suite domain: example.com
```

One option in this case:

- Create a Google Group.
- Give this new role to this new Google Group.
- Make this Google Group free to join.
- Tell people "hey, if you want to see my project SCHEMATA, join this group".

Then all will work.