# Permission denied when using BigQuery public data set as a source

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

When setting up a source that points to a Big Query public data set and using the source() function to reference it in my dbt model, I get this error on dbt run:

```
Database Error
  Access Denied: Table bigquery-public-data:INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA: User does not have permission to query table bigquery-public-data:INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA.
```

It appears to be trying to query the information schema from the public data set. Is it possible to use a public data set as a source in my dbt project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected on earlier versions of dbt — it has to do with the fact that you can't grant permissions on `bigquery-public-data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` to the public ([related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891634/how-can-i-give-others-permission-to-read-my-information-schema-schemata-in-bigqu)).

Fortunately, this issue was resolved in dbt v0.17.0 ([relevant PR](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/pull/2382))— try [upgrading to that version](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/migration-guide/upgrading-to-0-17-0/) and the error should disappear!

Comment: I get the same error on version 0.21.0

Comment: I get also this error using dbt-CLI following the dbt-tutoriel trying to query `dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.customers` with dbt v0.21.0. I did not have any error when running `dbt debug`.

`dbt run`
```Database Error in model stg_customers (models/staging/stg_customers.sql)
  Access Denied: Table dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.customers: User does not have permission to query table dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.customers.
  compiled SQL at target/run/jaffle_shop/models/staging/stg_customers.sql```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my data processing location was in the EU / in the profiles.yml file changed it to US (also of course will need a dataset location in US) and bingo it ran as expected in the tutorial. I had it in Version DBT 1.x

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30738816)